# Long running JDBC transaction: Closed Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

I am using c3p0 for connection pooling and facing "Closed connection" error with large data sets. I expect my transaction to be atomic and to run for almost max 2 hours.

For large data sets, which take around 40-45 minutes in processing. When I try to persist this data in the DB, I get exceptions in the following sequence:

```
[WARN] [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
[WARN] [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection ] which will not be reported to listeners!
[ERROR] org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction: Could not toggle autocommit
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
[ERROR] org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction: JDBC rollback failed
[ERROR] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor: Application exception overridden by rollback exception.
```

I have tried exploring solution a lot and tried to update my configuration accordingly. 
Here is my C3P0 configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${...}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${...}" />
    <property name="user" value="${...}" />
    <property name="password" value="${...}" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="6000" />
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="1800" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3600" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="0" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" />
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="1" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
</bean>
```

Please help.

Comment: You had an earlier error and you are posting only the ultimate consequences of that original error, which could for example be that your database rollback segment is too small for the transaction

Comment: I could not see any other exceptions, yesterday I saw OOM error but I increased the JVM to 1GB and now there are no OOM errors but this. 
I want to understand, as per the above configuration how long my transaction can run before the flush() is invoked?

Comment: A possible explanation is that you don't do anything with your connection for a long time, and the database closes it to avoid wasting unused connections.

Comment: Exactly, I think that's what is happening. How can I keep the connection alive through out the processing. Actually this transaction is being run asynchronously in a worker thread, and that's why takes time. Please suggest.

Comment: @jbnizet But that's something c3po should routinely detect. The problem here is that a connection reported an error and wasn't released to the pool afterwards.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: c3p0 can test the connection before releasing it while it holds the connection in the pool of available connections. But once the connection has been borrowed from the pool, I doubt c3p0 does anything to keep it alive. It would need to start a parallel thread and execute queries using this connection to do that. That said, I agree with what you say: the connection keeps being used although it has already had an error. Probably an exception is being caught, and the catcher doesn't rollback the transaction and close the session as it should.

Comment: @KevindraSingh: check your database settings.

Comment: @JBNizet Exactly, it won't mess with your acquired connection in parallel. This message is received when c3po receives a new request (for another Statement, for example) from a Connection that has already been "involved in an accident".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Agreed. My point is that this accident could be the closing of the connection by the database because it considers it as unused, due to the long process not doing anything with this connection for a long time.

Comment: Kevindra, are you taking a long time just to *calculate* what to store into the database? Because if you're continuously writing to the DB, however little data at once, then it won't time out. But in any case, this error from C3PO means that you are swallowing exceptions from the database, which is a programming issue you must fix anyway.

Comment: And if you are taking a long time to calculate, then first calculate all you need and only then open a transaction with the database to write the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marko! You got it, i was validating the data that takes around 30-35 minutes, but the connection was established in the beginning, hence became inactive. I added a seperate @Transactional with REQUIRES_NEW propagation on top of my persistence layer. Which fixed the issue. Thanks all again! :)